# libmodbus: how to compile application including libmodbus library?

Tags: c, linux, modbus, libmodbus

I have a problem with compilation of my application, which is based on `libmodbus` library:
https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus

I have tried to compile it using this command:
`cc pkg-config --cflags --libs libmodbus modbus.c -o modbus`

But I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cckdtbWy.o: in function `main':
modbus.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `modbus_new_tcp_pi'
/usr/bin/ld: modbus.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `modbus_connect'
/usr/bin/ld: modbus.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `modbus_free'
/usr/bin/ld: modbus.c:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `modbus_connect'
/usr/bin/ld: modbus.c:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `modbus_read_bits'
/usr/bin/ld: modbus.c:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference to `modbus_close'
/usr/bin/ld: modbus.c:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `modbus_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I would appreciate any help!

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked through this problem and my solution is that:

**1.** Create `modbus.conf` file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`.

**2.** Run `sudo ldconfig`.

**3.** Compile your application/program with the following command:

`gcc <name>.c -o <name> -I/usr/local/include/modbus/ -lmodbus`

It has worked for me, but I am not sure whether the first step is necessary.

Comment: You can use `#include <modbus/modbus.h>` instead of `#include <modbus.h>` and compile with `gcc <name>.c -o <name> -lmodbus`

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the `libmodbus-dev`? You should try this: `sudo apt-get install -y libmodbus-dev`.

See v3.1.6 and v3.0.8: [libmodbus docs](https://libmodbus.org/documentation/)

Comment: I haven't seen that there is such an option. Documentation is not impressing and short of information. Anyway I have compiled my application using `pkg-config --libs --cflags libmodbus` , but the question is, may I use other `CFLAGS` and include other directories while compiling? Of course I will check that, but I would like to know what hides under `--cflags` parameter.